.str.replace method for pandas.series does not work as expected
I have encountered the issue in one particular stage of my project.
Replicate with following:
import pandas as pd
# Recreated a sample data
data = {
  "FailCodes": ['4301,4090,5003(1)'],  
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Want to replace the '(1)' with 'p1q'
print(df.FailCodes.str.replace('(1)','p1q'),'\n') # Not giving expected result
# compare to string object method from standard python, which gives desired result
print('4301,4090,5003(1)'.replace('(1)','p1q'),'\n')
# Can get wanted result with following longer code,but would like explanation why first approach giving the unexpected result.
print(df.FailCodes.str.replace('(','p').str.replace(')','q' ))


Unexpected result end like: 430p1q,4090,5003(p1q)
Expected result: 4301,4090,5003p1q


What is your pandas.__version__? Old pandas e.g. 2017: regular interpretation appears to be the default https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16808. Consider updating your environment.

Version would be '0.23.0'.  Really old, I know, I had to do other part of my data wrangling process without availability of  .split(str, expand = True)…though it turned out having all Fail Codes in single column better than split into 15, given 99% of records have 2 or less Fail Codes.
Probably an odd question: should I feel guilty updating to the newest version? as I am using Jupyter Notebook IDE under Anaconda distribution which I downloaded for free a few years ago.

No guilt in updating unless you have constraints such as machine etc. Still free to code.

Thanks, would give updating to new version a try when have the chance. Somehow, I did not get the option to upvote your comment, which pointed out the same reason as the answer by Andrej Kesely.

@Oca I wasn't aware of the answer, thank you for pointing out. Although I still think the tag does not apply. Neither the question nor the answer are about regex. It just happens to be in there. In the answer, you could interchange the regex=False with any hypothetical parameter and it would not change a thing. On the other hand, users searching for [regex] will probably not find this question useful. (I will delete this comment shortly not to leave any clutter around.)

You probably use older version of Pandas, where default argument is regex=True (and (1) is regular pattern). Put regex=False to .str.replace:
print(df.FailCodes.str.replace("(1)", "p1q", regex=False))

Prints:
0    4301,4090,5003p1q
Name: FailCodes, dtype: object


Thanks, this solve the root cause directly. The str.contains().sum() raised:
‘…2: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract…’
whenever counting FAIL codes like 4095(1), 5003(1)…and summed to 0
The solution when tried Copilot first that did not work out, was along the line of using escape character, and more complex than my work-around of aliasing ‘(1) with ‘p1q’ first with .str,replace()
